# How to improve performance of my nested for loop used for python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, numba

I have been using nested for loop for dataframe but my file contains a lot of rows (nearly 96k rows). How should I improve my speed. It is taking hours now to run my code. Can please someone help me in this. Also I tried to use Numba Jit still its taking long time.
I researched a lot about how to obtimize my code, but haven't got any solution yet. I tried to think of using lambda but not sure about how to use it here specifically. Not sure about vectorization. If that's possible can someone please help me with that.

Below is my code--

```
import xlsxwriter

excelFile = xlsxwriter.Workbook ("FlagResult.xlsx")
workSheet = excelFile.add_worksheet ()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from datetime import datetime
from numba import jit



df= pd.read_csv('Coconut_data.csv')
site= df['Site']
month= df['Month']
year= df['Year']
data_source= df['Data Source']
source_type = df['Sourcetype']

# df19= df[df['Year']==2019]
df19= df[df['Year']==2019]
site19= df19['Site']
month19= df19['Month']
year19= df19['Year']
st19= df19['Sourcetype']

df20= df[df['Year']==2020]
site20= df20['Site']
month20= df20['Month']
year20= df20['Year']
st20= df20['Sourcetype']

df21= df[df['Year']==2021]
site21= df21['Site']
month21= df21['Month']
year21= df21['Year']
st21= df21['Sourcetype']

df19['Unique19']= site19.map(str) + month19.map(str) + st19.map(str)
df20['Unique20']= site20.map(str) + month20.map(str) + st20.map(str)
df21['Unique21']= site21.map(str) + month21.map(str) + st21.map(str)


df19['Uniquex19']= site19.map(str) + month19.map(str)
df20['Uniquex20']= site20.map(str) + month20.map(str)
df21['Uniquex21']= site21.map(str) + month21.map(str)

pivot19 = pd.pivot_table(df19,index=['Unique19','Data Source','Sourcetype','Site','Month','Year','Uniquex19'],values=['Final Usage'], aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot20 = pd.pivot_table(df20,index=['Unique20','Data Source','Sourcetype','Site','Month','Year','Uniquex20'],values=['Final Usage'], aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot21 = pd.pivot_table(df21,index=['Unique21','Data Source','Sourcetype','Site','Month','Year','Uniquex21'],values=['Final Usage'], aggfunc=np.sum)

# print(pivot19, pivot20, pivot21)
 
print('\n')
print('\n')   
           
@jit

def check2019(): 
    r=1
    for index, values in pivot19.iterrows():
        
        if (index[1]=='Actuals'):
            count=0
            for idx, val in pivot20.iterrows():
                if(idx[1]=='Actuals'):
                    if (index[6]==idx[6]):
                        per= ((val-values)/values)*100
                        if (per > 50).bool():
                            if (per == math.inf).bool():
                                result= 'Usage was 0 for ', str(index[3]), ' in ', str(index[4]), str(index[5]), ' but not for ', str(idx[5])
                                count+=1
                                r+=1
                                res = ''.join(result)
                                print(res)
                                workSheet.write(r,1,str(res))
                                break
                            else:
                                 result= str(index[3]) ,' for ', str(index[4]), str(index[5]), ' from ', str(index[2]), ' has increased by ', str(abs(round(float(per),2))), ' % in ', str(idx[5])
                                 count+=1
                                 r+=1
                                 res = ''.join(result)
                                 print(res)
                                 workSheet.write(r,1,str(res))
                                 break
                                 
                        elif (per < -50).bool():
                            result= str(index[3]) ,' for ', str(index[4]), str(index[5]), ' from ', str(index[2]), ' has dropped by ', str(abs(round(float(per),2))), ' % in ', str(idx[5])
                            count+=1
                            r+=1
                            res = ''.join(result)
                            print(res)
                            workSheet.write(r,1,str(res))
                            break
                            
                        else:
                            # result= 'No spike or drop observed for ', str(index[3]), ' in ', index[4], str(index[5])
                            # count+=1
                            # r+=1
                            # res = ''.join(result)
                            # print(res)
                            # workSheet.write(r,1,str(res))
                            break
                            
            if count==0:
                result= 'Missing ', str(index[3]), ' in ', str(index[4]), ' ', str(idx[5])
                r+=1
                res = ''.join(result)
                print(res)
                workSheet.write(r,1,str(res))
                
                
check2019()
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your data, and give a brief explanation of what you are tying to achieve with the function?

Comment: Actually I am working on to compare the energy consumption sites between 2019 and 2020 year and to see if there is a drop or increase in the usage for that site between same months ( i.e. like april 2019 to april 2020). Also if the site it not present for the next month then print that missing site. Also, in my raw file, I have multiple rows for same sites for same month with different usage, hence added then by pivots. Below I can share a sample -

Comment: Country Name State Year Data Source Site Month Data Source by Month Intervalenddate Intervalstartdate Site Category Site Type Sourcetype Final Usage
 
United States CA 2019 Actuals SBY1 DECEMBER Actuals 12/16/2019 12/17/2019 #### #### URJNEET 238329 
Japan Chiba 2020 Proxy CFS1 MAY Proxy Estimates 07/25/2020 05/01/20 **** **** PROXYData 321221

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to give you a more precise answer in regard to vectorisation or improving your for loop without seeing the underlying data and having a sense of what you're doing to it.

However, it seems to me like you have quite a lot of specific stuff going on in your nested for loops that already works.

So this approach may be a neater fix... It splits your dataframe into chunks so you can process these chunks one at a time using a generator expression, which will save a lot on system memory. That should make for quite a big performance improvement and hopefully save you from having to significantly rewrite the for loop logic.

```
def split_df_into_chunks(df, n):
    """
    Splits a dataframe into n chunks so each one can be processed at a time.
    :param df: pandas dataframe.
    :param n: int, number of rows to include in each chunk.
    :return chunks: generator expression.
    """
    chunks = (df.loc[x : x + n - 1] for x in list(range(len(df)))[::n])
    return chunks

df_sections = split_df_into_chunks(your_df, 3)

try:
    while True:
        check2019(next(df_sections))
except StopIteration:
    print('Finished processing dataframes')
finally:
    del df_sections
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but to show you need to think about what you need to get out of the code and look for existing functionality.  It's likely someone has done something similar before or there are standard methods available in the API to process your input quickly.  For just one example...

If you wanted to do a percentage change comparison you could, for example, look at [pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) and try...

```
import pandas as pd

values = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=3, freq='5W')

df = pd.DataFrame({'SiteA': [75.52,75.12,85.21],'SiteB': [70.21,69.21,72.21],'SiteC':[90.14,82.1,45.27]}, index=values)

print(round(df.pct_change(axis=0),2))
```

That outputs:

```
            SiteA   SiteB   SiteC
2021-01-03  NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-02-07  -0.01   -0.01   -0.09
2021-03-14  0.13    0.04    -0.45
```

You should notice I'm not writing `per= ((val-values)/values)*100` where `val` and `values` are from a for loop over a dataframe; and I'm not saying where to write them.

Now, the input to that is a dataframe like this...

```
            SiteA   SiteB   SiteC
2021-01-03  75.52   70.21   90.14
2021-02-07  75.12   69.21   82.10
2021-03-14  85.21   72.21   45.27
```

Step one for you is to wrangle (clean, move, shuffle, shift, whatever) your data input as best you can and get it as organized as possible.  Then look around (search) for "pandas how do I compare one year to another as a percentage change"...etc.  If you get stuck (we all do), you should post a new question and say "here's part of my code...it does this, but I want it to do this.  I've tried this...but it errors with...

The code is probably out there already.